# Facing issue with migrating Cucumber 6.x to 7.x latest version

Tags: cucumber, testng, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

Facing issue with migrating Cucumber 6.x to 7.x latest version.

I was using Cucumber 6.x version and my automation test running smoothly with it.
But with new project requirements, I've to migrate my cucumber-java version from 6.x to 7.x and want to use enhanced cucumber hooks in my automation framework.

@AfterAll hook is available from 7.x version only.

I'm sharing required information

- pom.xml content
- console ERROR logs
- SequentialRunnerTest.java file

In case of any missing information, please let me know.

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <cucumber.version>7.3.4</cucumber.version>
        <maven.surefire.version>2.22.2</maven.surefire.version>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
        <html-formatter.version>9.0.0</html-formatter.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20210307</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tech.grasshopper</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber6-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.36</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

**Console ERROR logs**

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.4.0
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class com.proj.Runner.SequentialRunnerTest
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:30)
    at org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.instantiateUsingDefaultConstructor(InstanceCreator.java:193)
    at org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.createInstanceUsingObjectFactory(InstanceCreator.java:113)
    at org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.createInstance(InstanceCreator.java:79)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.dispense(SimpleObjectDispenser.java:25)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.dispense(GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.java:30)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:112)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:165)
    at org.testng.TestClass.getInstances(TestClass.java:122)
    at org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances(TestClass.java:102)
    at org.testng.TestClass.init(TestClass.java:94)
    at org.testng.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:59)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:463)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:339)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:292)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:223)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:33)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:66)
    at org.testng.ITestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(ITestRunnerFactory.java:55)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:659)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:173)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:107)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1300)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1276)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1125)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:23)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/messages/internal/com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageV3
    at io.cucumber.core.plugin.PluginFactory.newInstance(PluginFactory.java:120)
    at io.cucumber.core.plugin.PluginFactory.instantiate(PluginFactory.java:99)
    at io.cucumber.core.plugin.PluginFactory.create(PluginFactory.java:63)
    at io.cucumber.core.plugin.Plugins.createPlugins(Plugins.java:32)
    at io.cucumber.core.plugin.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:25)
    at io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.<init>(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:108)
    at io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.<init>(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:65)
    at com.proj.Runner.SequentialRunnerTest.<init>(SequentialRunnerTest.java:56)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/messages/internal/com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageV3
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter.<init>(ExtentCucumberAdapter.java:91)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at io.cucumber.core.plugin.PluginFactory.newInstance(PluginFactory.java:116)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.cucumber.messages.internal.com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 47 more
```

SequentialRunnerTest.java file

```
public class SequentialRunnerTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    TestNGCucumberRunner testngcucumber = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());

    /** The log. */
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SequentialRunnerTest.class.getName());
    private static Properties CONFIG = PropertyHelper.getConfig(Constants.CONFIG_PROPERTY);

    public static void getScenariosName() {
        
        for (int counter = 0; counter < Variables.scenarios.size(); counter++) {              
              System.out.println("************"+ Variables.scenarios.get(counter));         
          }  
    }
    
    @AfterAll
    public static void SendEmail() throws EmailException, IOException {     
    }

}
```

Am I making use of any transitive dependencies over here? Or using non-compatible libraries over here?

Can someone please suggest possible root-cause and solution for the same?

Comment: Comment the extentreports adapter dependency or use the correct [version 7](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/tech.grasshopper/extentreports-cucumber7-adapter/1.5.1)

Comment: Thanks @Grasshopper - it works post updating adapter dependency to extentreports-cucumber7-adapter 1.5.1 version.
So we have to use extentreports-cucumber7-adapter with cucumber-java 7.x version.

Answer (score 0):

Migration from 6.x to 7.x, make sure you are using all distribution of 7.x only.

- cucumber-java
- cucumber-testng
- cucumber-picocontainer
- extentreports-cucumber7-adapter

That's it. Run Automation test cases- you will get smooth results just like before.

Thanks.!!